# SPSS: Comparing prevalences

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, spss, standard-deviation

I have a dataset of couples presenting themselves to the infertility clinic and would like to compare the prevalence of certain diseases in this group to the prevalence of these diseases in the general population. 
For this I have looked up these prevalences in the general population in scientific articles, but I do not have the datasets on which these were based, nor a standard deviation or confidence interval. I only have the dataset of the couples and thus the prevalence and standard deviation of the diseases they presented themselves with.

Is there any way to compare these two prevalences in SPSS to see if there is a significant difference between these two?

Comment: Do you have any information about the general population? A mean? Do you at least have a general idea about what you can expect in the general population?

Comment: I have the prevalences of these diseases in the general population.

Comment: Estimate the mean and confidence interval for the data that you do have (the abnormal group) and check whether the population mean is contained in the sample mean confidence interval.